# handling Callable, CompletableFuture and Flux

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

As of spring 5 seems like Flux/Mono can be also be a returned value of spring rest controller method. 
I looked at spring reference guide 4.3 and read a pretty nice description of how Callable and DeferredResult are handled (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-async)
I also read on some blog posts that CompletableFuture can also be returned from controller methods. If it is true than can anybody shed some light how 
CompletableFuture and Flux/Mono are handled in Spring MVC ? 
Are they handled more less the same way as DeferredResult/Callable, i.e. "processing" done in an external thread and then Spring MVC dispatches the request back to DispatcherServlet (so the HTTP Response is written to and flushed on servlet container thread)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as of Spring Framework 5.0 Spring MVC can handle Publisher-like return types in controller handlers. Depending on the cardinality of the returned type (one or multiple possible values?), Spring MVC will handle it with:

- a `DeferredResult` if returning a single value
- a `DeferredResult<List<?>>` if it's returning an asynchronous collection, collecting all elements in a list
- a `ResponseBodyEmitter` or `SseEmitter` if you're streaming data to the client

Now the underlying processing model is using Servlet 3.0 async support, moving the blocking I/O operations to a non-container thread, dispatching back to the container when it's done.

On the other hand, Spring WebFlux is fully asynchronous and non-blocking (using Servlet 3.1 support for Servlet containers); in that case, fewer threads will be used.

More on that in [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-reactive-types).

Comment: thx a lot. Based on last paragraph of https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-reactive-types does it mean that spring MVC uses SyncTaskExecutor for writing to ServletResponseOutputStream (to not block "event-loop thread") but at the same time this particular executor shall not be used on production ? So In spring mvc if i wanna use reactive types as controller return methods shall i explicitly configure MVC TaskExecutor ? Why MVC TaskExecutor does not need to be configured for DeferredResult in Spring 4.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

This video nicely explains what's going on in spring mvc https://www.infoq.com/presentations/servlet-reactive-stack. Simply `startAsync` is used to resume(dispatch) to servlet thread to write (in a blocking way) to servlet response.